# Mockito: Do extra actions before thenCallRealMethod()

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

How can I do extra actions (e.g. logging, call other methods,...) before calling `thenCallRealMethod()` using Mockito ?

```
Mockito.when(student.calculateGrade())
       .pipe(() -> {
           System.out.println("blabla");
           doSomethingElse("...");
       }).thenCallRealMethod();
```

Is there anything like the pipe() method in the code above ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with `thenAnswer`:

```
when(student.calculateGrade()).thenAnswer(invocation -> {
            System.out.println("Log something");
            return invocation.callRealMethod();
        });
```